# How to block a user from installing/uninstalling applications?

Tags: user-management

I want to block a user from installing or uninstalling any application in the system. Does anybody know how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't give the user administrator rights. You need those to install or uninstall a program.

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)